# Return large objects completely

Tags: deno

We start Deno.exe from C# and communicate with through the process Input and Output streams. When I return very large objects from Deno, they will get shortened:

for instance if I have an array of 6k nodes and want to return it to the C# process, deno will reply:

```
[
  { obj1 : true },
  { obj1 : true },
  ...5898 more items <- I need these
]
```

How can I get Deno to return the entire array through stdout?

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: Can you explain the use case more?  Are you trying to print each object or do something else?  You could possibly loop through and print line by line if that's all that you need.

Comment: If you’re not looking for [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) output… you can use [`Deno.inspect`](https://deno.land/api@v1.31.2?s=Deno.inspect), setting various limit-related [options](https://deno.land/api@v1.31.2?s=Deno.InspectOptions) to `Infinity` in order to prevent truncation during serialization. If that addresses your question, I can write it up as an answer — otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi sorry, the code is litterally where I enter a large json array into the stdin to execute it, so it echos back. So it just evaluates an expression of array and returns that. Only when it does a lot of elements are omitted.

Comment: So the use case is running custom javascript code. I currently use Clearscript with V8, that has an Evaluate method that will execute dynamic javascript. I want to move to typescript so looking at deno b/c it has a lot out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for JSON. As far as I know, the JSON representation of objects should evaluate identically to the javascript object for simple objects (which this appears to be). I would change the code to something along the lines of:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Alternatively, if you insist on not using JSON (which could be valid for a few reasons), `Deno.inspect` is something you could use.

```
console.log(Deno.inspect(output, {
  colors: false,
  depth: 2, // probably change this
  iterableLimit: 10000, // probably change this
  strAbbreviateSize: 10000000, // probably change this
}));
```